# Laravel 5 not finding css files

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

I've just installed a Laravel 5 project on MAMP and my pages are not finding the css files.

This is the link to my css in my app.blade.php file:

```
<link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And my .htaccess file has this line:

```
RewriteBase /laravel-site/laravel-5-app/public/
```

In the config folder my app.php file contains this:

```
'url' => 'http://localhost:8888/laravel-site/laravel-5-app/public/',
```

But when I open up this page: http://localhost:8888/laravel-site/laravel-5-app/public/auth/login and check the developer tools, it is looking for the css file at this location: http://localhost:8888/css/app.css

Just as a side note, if I go to this url: http://localhost:8888/laravel-site/laravel-5-app/public/ I get the correct welcome page.

Comment: As for the link maybe try  `<link href="{{ public_path() }}/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">`.

Comment: Now it is looking for the css file here: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel-site/laravel-5-app/public/css/app.css (which i where it is) but it still not showing it on the page, but if I copy that link to the address bar it finds the css file.

Comment: modify app.blade.php's css/app.css link like this. `<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Use this to add assets like `css`, `javascript`, `images`.. into blade file.

**FOR CSS,**

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

OR

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

**FOR JS,**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/custom.js') }}"></script>
```

OR

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/custom.js') }}"></script>
```

**FOR IMAGES,**

```
{{ asset('img/photo.jpg'); }}
```

Here is the [DOC](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls)

*Alternatively*, if you pulled the composer package `illuminate/html` which was come as default in laravel 4.2 then you can use like below, In laravel 5. you have to manually pull the package.

```
{{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }}
```

Here is an [Example](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/184/generating-a-link-to-a-css-file).

Comment: @davelowe85 Because you're expected to use `php artisan serve` or Homestead for development, and a proper server config in production. `public` should **never** be in your URLs (if it is, your app is potentially vulnerable to compromise) and Laravel is typically run at the root of a domain name, so `/css/app.css` is a perfectly fine default for sensible setups.

Comment: This is a way of doing it, but you should really look into using elixir

Comment: The word **blade** needs to be emphasized more

Comment: these things are not working on my production server(shared hosting)! any idea why?

Comment: and what is the solution for Laravel mix()?  Because url() is working for me correctly, but mix is not finding the /public folder...

Answer (score 28):

In the root path create a .htaccess file with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f



RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 
#RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

In public directory create a .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

if you have done any changes in public/index.php file correct them with the right path then your site will be live.

what will solve with this?

- Hosting issue of laravel project.
- Css not work on laravel.
- Laravel site not work.
- laravel site load with domain/public/index.php
- laravel project does not redirect correctly

Answer (score 13):

`Stop artisan serve`

and try using

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public
```

Comment: This solves issue with windows directories and permissions, also works great on linux. Thank you

Comment: could you please explain this command

Comment: an explanation would be appreciated

Answer (score 10):

You can use one of the following options:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

---

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

---

```
{!! Html::style( asset('css/app.css')) !!}
```

Answer (score 7):

It's works.
For css:

```
<link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Try to:

```
 <link href="public/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 2):

To fast apply simple regex.

```
search : href="(.+?)"
replace : href="{{ asset('$1') }}"
```

and

```
search : src="(.+?)"
replace : src="{{ asset('$1') }}"
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - where should that be applied and why?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution

```
  {!! Html::style('css/select2.min.css') !!}
  {!! Html::script('js/select2.min.js') !!}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

If you migrated .htaccess file from public directory to project folder and altered  server.php to index.php in project folder then this should works for you.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/css/app.css') }}" type="text/css">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, until just now.

Removing the `/` from before  `/css/app.css` so that its `css.app.css` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `laravel`  5 or 6:

1. Inside Public folder create .css, .js, images... folders

[image]

2. Then inside your blade file you can display an images using this code :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link src="/images/test.png">
<!-- / is important and dont write public folder-->
```

Answer (score 1):

I used:

```
"{{asset('css/custom.css')}}"
"{{asset('css/app.css') }}"
```

First one is my own file the second one came with laravel. I'm using version 5.

http://spanibox.com/css/app.css 
works but 
http://spanibox.com/css/custom.css
does not. I find this very weird.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel version 6.0.2

I also had the same problem. I used

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

And after moving the CSS folder from folder resource to folder public it works

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
If it's a css file tap

```html
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

If it's an image tap

```html
<link href="{{ asset('css/img/logo.png') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

Comment: When adding an answer to a five year old question with seventeen existing answers it is important to include an explanation and to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and this is how I solved this. In .env file I have updated APP_URL value to server url. In case of localhost APP_URL=http://localhost:8000

after this stopped server and started server again

Answer (score -1):

my opinion is that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::to('/css/app.css') }}">
```

is the best method to route to your css files.

The `URL::to()` also works for js

Answer (score -1):

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">`if you are using laravel 5 or 6 you should create folder css and call it with

it works for me

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer, such that others can learn from it

Comment: yes inside your public folder create anouther folders (CSS ,JS, ...) and to use it we should add "/" befoure link of our file but without public it is obligatoire in laravel 5 or 6 i wish that good

Comment: Please add all explanation **to the answer** by editing it

Answer (score -2):

You can simply create assets in public and added more paths and call in your head html the following code

Answer (score -2):

if you are on ubuntu u can try these commands:

```
sudo apt install npm

npm install && npm run dev
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - why should that solve the given problem?

Answer (score -2):

Simply you can put a back slash in front of your css link

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. A backslash in a URL sounds strange