# How to include CSS in laravel 5 running with artisan?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I am new to Laravel and am trying to get the css in the public directory to load. The page loads no problem but the CSS gives me a 404 error in firebug:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/main.css"
```

I wrote this in the blade template:

```
<link href="{{ asset('/css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Which outputs:

```
<link href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Which seems correct.

The site is run with php artisan serve. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Try `{{ asset('css/main.css') }}`

Comment: Just tried, still gives me a 404, it outputs the same thing: `<link href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: this should work <link href="/asset/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8000/asset/css/main.css"`

Comment: Does it work when you paste same thing to browser?

Comment: No, pasted http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/main.css into the url bar and got 404:
The requested resource /css/main.css was not found on this server.

Comment: Where have you put all your css files inside public folder if not put everything inside public folder not at root folder

Comment: All my css is in ./public/css

Comment: Have you included the html facades if you are using laravel 5? check you app.php in the config folder and check the aliases.

Comment: Yes, I've added them. HTML and Form work fine, tested them on a different view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

`<link href="{{asset('css/main.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">`

OR

`<link href="{{url('css/main.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">`

OR

If you are using **php artisan serve** its possible that your public folder is not being used, so use PHP native server instead and specify the public folder as the web root.

Stop `artisan serve` and try using PHP native server by issuing this command at the root of your Laravel project: `php -S localhost:8000 -t public`

Comment: Tried it now, still the same 404

Comment: Please where is CSS file located in your public folder?

Comment: The default location: ./public/css/main.css

Comment: Correct. Running it with `php artisan serve`

Comment: okay. If you are using Laravel 5 go to config/app.php and set 'url' in the stack to `'url' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'` and try again

Comment: Did that, same error. Can't detect anything in the public folder. Maybe its a problem with artisan?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Cleared the cache, still no luck

Comment: Try permission 777 to that folder @BenjaminDowson

Comment: Okay. Please stop `artisan serve` and try using PHP native server by issuing this command at the root of your Laravel project: `php -S localhost:8000 -t public`

Comment: For point your current directory run: php -S localhost:8000 -t ./

Answer (score 0):

If you install Illuminate/HTML
you can do

```
{!!HTML::style('css/styles.css')!!} //styles.css inside public/css folder
```

or try

```
{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a path for your css and JS files, **the root of the files need to be in 'project-name\public\'** and not 'project-name\'

If you want for example to include with blade 'mytheme.css' which is inside 'mypersonalcss' folder ('mypersonnalcss\mytheme.css') fist add it to the project in 'project-name\public\mypersonnalcss\mytheme.css'

Then add it in your blade file :

```
<link href="{{ asset('mypersonnalcss\mytheme.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

Please see : [Laravel 5 not finding css files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214499/laravel-5-not-finding-css-files) to learn more about how to add assets to blade files.