# using php artisan serve cant load any js / css in public folder?

Tags: javascript, css, laravel

i have xampp control panel v3.2.2, php version 5.6.24, and my laravel version is 5.4.32. in windows 7 32-bit

i was create project laravel using `composer create-project laravel/laravel simpleproject --prefer-dist` and i do `php artisan make:auth`

my question when im running my apps using `php artisan serve` and use localhost:8000 they not load any css file and js file in my public folder.

when im running my apps using localhost/simpleproject/public/ its going normal and haven't problem with load any css and js

Comment: how did you load the assets? what is the error in browser console?

Comment: <link href="{{ asset('/css/app.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"> and error console =
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

Comment: Please show the code how you load your assets in your views/layout/template file.

Comment: please try this http://douglastarr.com/how-to-allow-unsafe-ports-in-chrome

Comment: still cant load css and js, i use "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --explicitly-allowed-ports=80,8000,433,81,84

Comment: add permission to your public folder, not loading means 404 error in console ?

Comment: @MasoudHaghbin i mean when i running localhost:8000 cannot call my js and my css in folder public and throw error in console ******Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE*****

Answer (score 7):

now i can use localhost:8000 and load all of my file in public folder with command Laravel project: `php -S localhost:8000 -t public` reference from [How to include CSS in laravel 5 running with artisan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739734/how-to-include-css-in-laravel-5-running-with-artisan?rq=1)