# Uncaught SyntaxError: illegal character U+001F in JS and CSS files

Tags: javascript, php, css, httpd.conf

I am encountering a bug with a new Laravel 7 project (using Webpack,Laravel-Mix, etc. on default configuration) on my localhost (MacOS Big Sur, M1 Silicon, PHP7.4 and HTTPd 2.4).

When my browser reach a JS or a CSS file, each file begins with an apparent header in plain text.

```
‹���������������HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: localhost:8000
Date: Thu, 21 Jan 2021 08:27:03 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 1737901

/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
etc.
```

In the console log, and for the JavaScript files, there is the message :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: illegal character U+001F
```

I tried search about this problem (php.ini, httpd.conf, etc.), but i didn't found anything.

Comment: No solution if I switch between PHP 7.4 and PHP 8. Maybe a problem with httpd.conf ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using this command to start the server: `php -S localhost:8000 -t public`

Resource: [using php artisan serve cant load any js / css in public folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45530671/using-php-artisan-serve-cant-load-any-js-css-in-public-folder)

Answer (score 0):

- Kill Laravel's artisan.
- Restart httpd.
- Restart php7.4.
- Restart artisan.
  Seems to have worked...

Comment: got the same issue, i folowed the steps but still have the same probleme