# React and php wrong file

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

Well, honestly I didn't know how to make the question, sorry. But the thing is. I'm making something with react and php backend, but when I run the server with "sudo php artisan serve" nothing appears, that is because it's taking a wrong "app.js" this is some of my code:

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import Master from './components/Master';
import CreateProduct from './components/CreateProduct';
import DisplayProduct from './components/DisplayProduct';
import UpdateProduct from './components/UpdateProduct';

render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={Master} >
        <Route path="/add-item" component={CreateProduct} />
        <Route path="/display-item" component={DisplayProduct} />
        <Route path="/edit/:id" component={UpdateProduct} />
      </Route>
    </Router>,
        document.getElementById('crud-app'));
```

welcome.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Laravel 5.5 ReactJS CRUD</title>
        <!-- <link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="crud-app"></div>
        <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

as I say when I run the server it takes a "app.js" that is in "proyect/public/js/app.js" however the file I want to appear is in "proyect/resources/js/app.js" how can I do to get the file I want?

Comment: The `resources` directory is not for public-facing files. That's why you have a `public` directory. Just move the file.

Comment: Tried that but when I compile with "sudo npm run dev" it erases the file and replaces with some node backend. And that's when I get the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include CSS in laravel 5 running with artisan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739734/how-to-include-css-in-laravel-5-running-with-artisan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this question and answers given:
[How to include CSS in laravel 5 running with artisan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739734/how-to-include-css-in-laravel-5-running-with-artisan?rq=1)

Basically your asset files should be in public folder as your public folder is root folder when you run your server with serve command.