# Loading assets when creating Laravel 5 packages

Tags: php, laravel

When creating a Laravel 5 package, how do I load assets like CSS/JS files? My working package currently has controllers and views, but all the CSS is placed in the header of each view which isn't good.

**Edit:** Thanks for your answers, but perhaps I wasn't being too clear. My question is in reference to a Laravel package and not a Laravel app. In this case, I load views using Service Providers

```
// Views
$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/Views', 'packagename');
```

The above line is placed in the `register()` method.

Comment: How do you publish the views? Do the same thing with css/js, publishing them to the "public/" folder (preferably something like `public/vendor/packagename/assets/js/`)

Answer (score 2):

From the docs on publishing assets for packages: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/packages#public-assets

Public Assets
Your package may have assets such as JavaScript, CSS, and images. To publish these assets to the application's public directory, use the service provider's publishes method. In this example, we will also add a public asset group tag, which may be used to publish groups of related assets:

```
/**
 * Perform post-registration booting of services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/path/to/assets' => public_path('vendor/courier'),
    ], 'public');
}
```

Now, when your package's users execute the vendor:publish command, your assets will be copied to the specified publish location. Since you will typically need to overwrite the assets every time the package is updated, you may use the --force flag:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=public --force
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/master/structure):

> > The `public` directory contains the front controller and your assets (images, JavaScript, CSS, etc.).

My usual structure is as follows:

```
/public
    /css
    /js
    index.php
```

Then, easily in your blade template you can add those assets like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

Recently I found that in some cases this will cause a 404. To insure you always get the resource loaded, you can use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}" >
```

The docs for this can be found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls), and you can refer to [this previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214499/laravel-5-not-finding-css-files) regarding this issue.