# Laravel route returning public folder

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I have a simple Laravel project. In routes I specified that `/` returns `index.php` view. Now I want additionaly to get directed on my public folder with images, css etc, by adding something more to the link lets say `/css/index.css` would return me `localhost/projects/myproject/public/css/index.css` How do I reach `/public` folder through `/` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214499/laravel-5-not-finding-css-files/28214659#28214659 this may helps you

Answer (score 1):

## 1st Method

Use this to add assets like `css`, `javascript`, `images`.. in to blade file.

**FOR CSS,**

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

OR

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

**FOR JS,**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/custom.js') }}"></script>
```

OR

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/custom.js') }}"></script>
```

**FOR IMAGES,**

```
{{ asset('img/photo.jpg'); }}
```

here is the [Laravel Doc](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls)

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28214659/2117868

---

## 2nd Method

or you can use this syntax for adding `css` and `javascript` by adding [laravelcollective](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) package and register the service provider and aliases

then,

```
{!! HTML::style('link/to/your/css/file.css') !!}
{!! HTML::script('link/to/your/js/file') !!}
```

**Remember** here `{!! HTML::style() !!}` will directly point the file in `public` directory.

So, writing `{!! Html::style('style.css') !!}` will point the `style.css` file in `public` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your routes should have a closure or call to Controller function. e.g

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
     return 'some message'
});
```

or

```
Route::get('/', SomeController@somefunction);
```

I suggest using second option if you are returning views (because obviously generating views without dynamic data is waste of the framework). So if you do so you would have something like :

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SomeController extends Controller {

public function somefunction()
{
 //fetch some data if required
  return view('index');//which is a file under resources/views namely index.blade.php
}
```

Now in your index.blade.php you may call your css as you do in your normal HTML pages butif you want it laravel way you should :

```
{!! HTML::style('link/to/your/css/file.css') !!}

{!! HTML::script('link/to/your/js/file') !!}
```

but make sure if you are using second method you should require [laravelcollective](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) package and register he service provider and aliases