# Why I can't obtain the complete path of a CSS resource in a blade template?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

I am very new in Laravel. I am working on a Laravel 5.4 application and I have the following problem using blade to retrieve the comple URL of a CSS resource.

This is my **app.blade.php** file representing the template of all my views:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!--<link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <!--<link href="{{ URL::asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >-->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container" style="width: 60%; margin-bottom: 50px;">
        @yield('content')
    </div>

    @yield('footer')

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, folloing this SO post: [Laravel 5 not finding css files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214499/laravel-5-not-finding-css-files)

I am defining this CSS resource in this way:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

to retrieve the **http://localhost/HotelRegistration/public/css/app.css** resource from the correct place.

The problem is that doing in this way opening an URL like http://localhost/HotelRegistration/public/registration

I still obtain the wrong CSS link in the generated page, this one:

```
<link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Doing in this way I expected to obtain the correct one **http://localhost/HotelRegistration/public/css/app.css**

I also tried to import it using this alternative link:

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

but I am obtaining the same results.

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue and obtain the correct url of my CSS including the entire path?

Comment: to work with Laravel you should use Virtual Host but not localhost

Comment: @lubart I know but what happens if I have to put in on a remote server and there is not yet a domain?

Comment: remote server always has IP address at least... you also should set up a webserver there

Comment: @lubart yes I will access to an address as: MY_IP/MYWEBSITE. But I think that doing in thiw way I will have the problem that opening an URL like MY_IP/MYWEBSITE/HotelRegistration/public/registration my CSS files still not work

Comment: I suppose it is origin of your problem, url should be like YOUR_IP/registration, not MY_IP/MYWEBSITE/public/registration and Directory on webserver set as MYWEBSITE/public. But if for some reason you cannot control webserver, you can use redirection in .htaccess, just use rewrite mod

Comment: Try adding a leading slash to the asset: `{{URL::asset('/css/app.css')}}` also if you don't do a vhost then you can't use relative URLs and laravel doesn't really support that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is a good idea to use artisan serve:

```
php artisan serve
```

This will reduces a lot of headaches. If you are on a Mac, try `valet`. It is really nice and light.

Second you need to import css in following manner:

```
<link href="{!! asset('css/app.css') !!}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: What exactly does php artisan serve statment?

Comment: according to docs, it serves the folder that you are in as development server and make it accessible trough its default port which is **8000** . In another word you do not need to write complete path to your local server folder. You can also change the port to another port. For example `php artisan serve --port=8080` . Remember that using some ports require super user permissions so you need to put `sudo` before your command.

Comment: This is not a good idea. One should know basic stuff about web server configuration if plans to be a good backend web programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a virtual host in apache config files your root is the public dir not your localhost root (replace YOUR_LOCALHOST_ROOT_PATH of course) :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin test@test.com
DocumentRoot YOUR_LOCALHOST_ROOT_PATH/HotelRegistration/public
ServerName hotel.dev
<Directory "YOUR_LOCALHOST_ROOT_PATH/HotelRegistration/public">
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Of course hotel.dev does not exist on the internet, no problem, use your system host file !
In your host file (on windows : C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/host , linux /etc/host )
add this line :

```
127.0.0.1 hotel.dev
```

you can add more line too :

```
127.0.0.1 hotel.dev another.dev youtestsite.dev
```

Restart your browser and apache it should work immediatly

And use http://hotel.dev

You should not have any path problem after that !

Answer (score -1):

If you work on your localhost, you should **run command line** from **your directory root project** (e.g.: HotelRegistration/) :

```
php artisan serve
```

By default you will can access your project with url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ and you css link will look like http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/app.css

If you want to host on your remote server, you can use **.htaccess** rewrite mode redirect to **index.php** of **public directory**.