# laravel 5- css and js are not loading with URL::assets

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 and I have problem with the assets url , I do not manage to call css to or js links

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="{{ asset('/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

the url in html is: http://localhost/site/js/...js.

I have tried to add public but still not working

got

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Comment: remove the first slash on the dir..

Comment: Still not working thanks

Comment: What you are getting is a 404 error, I don't think it's css or js not loading.

Comment: Check you have those files in Poublic/js & Public/css

Comment: Can you check if you got the files inside of `public/js` and `public/css`?

Answer (score 2):

honestly, just try it like this,

```
<link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The / at the start of the address will asume you are at starting from the root of your server, which is the public directory.

Answer (score 2):

Change `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php/asset()` function as follows:

```
function asset($path, $secure = null)
{
   return app('url')->asset("public/".$path, $secure);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `<script src="{{ URL::asset('/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>`

to

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Notice the `/` before js, possibly the reason why your css and js links are not working.
Do same on the css as well.

Comment: Do you actually have `jquery.min.js` inside `public/js` directory?

Answer (score 0):

Do:

1. php artisan config: clear
2. php artisan cache: clear
3. delete public/css and public/js
4. gulp
5. try it again

you have to put your css, js, images etc in the public folder. The root of the asset method is the public folder so if you have a public/css/style.css file, you can get its path by using asset('css/style.css').

The asset folder is for storing less or sass files which have to be compiled into a css file.

Comment: The problem could be on your htaccess or permissions.

Try to temporarily remove htaccess and try to access directly the css file. If the problem persists then you should try to chmod public/css folder and the files in to 777 and try again.

Check again the path to the css file and its name. @user450_user

Answer (score 0):

This is duplicate question. you can find my answer here also:

[Why I can't obtain the complete path of a CSS resource in a blade template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43372911/why-i-cant-obtain-the-complete-path-of-a-css-resource-in-a-blade-template/43376757#43376757)

Do you see default laravel `js` and `css` files in `resources folder`? put your files there. I found this place the most convenient one.

You can load them in your blade like this: 
`<link href="{!! asset('css/app.css') !!}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >`

if you are still facing problem try to run this on you project folder first and then try:

`php artisan serve`

I hope it work for you. Any question just let me know.

Comment: If you feel like it is a duplicate question, you should flag it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Node version from 15.* to 12.13.0 helped me to install node modules & then I did gulp & now everything works smooth!! yeah!!