# laravel show method doesn't have the style

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, laravel

I'm new on laravel and i'm trying to make on-many relationship between category table and devices table on database 
in Category view i have all the category and i want when i clik to one category to go to another view and show all the devices of this category
It work's with my using rsource controller for the category and in the show method : `CatgoryController.php`

```
 public function show($id)
{
    $categories = Category::find($id);
    $all_devices = $categories->devices;

    return view('devices',compact('categories',$categories,'all_devices',$all_devices));
}
```

and in the devices view i do: 
`devices.blade.php`

```html
@extends('master')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center animateup">
     <div class="inline-icons-text section-heading">
      <div class="inline-icon">
       <hr/><hr/><hr/><hr/><hr/>
      </div>
      <span class="inline-icon heading-width">
       <span class="heading-text"><h1> {{$categories->category_name}} </h1> </span>
      </span>
      <div class="inline-icon">
       <hr/><hr/><hr/><hr/><hr/>
      </div>
     </div>
                </div>
   </div> 

 <br/>
 <div class="row text-center">
    @foreach ($all_devices as $device)
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 animateleft">
     <h5>
      <a href="#">{{$device->device_name}}</a>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </h5>
    </div>
    @endforeach
   </div>
</div>

@stop
```

this is how i show all the category and when click on one it goes to anthor view to show the devics of this category

`categories.blade.php`

```html
   <div class="row text-center">
    @foreach ($categories as $categories)
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 animateleft">
     <h5>
      <a href="categories/{{$categories->id}}">{{$categories->category_name}}</a>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </h5>
    </div>
    @endforeach
   </div>
```

and finally this my rout `Rout.php`

```
Route::resource('categories','CategoryController');

Route::resource('/devices','DevicesController');
```

**My Problem** is that evry thing work but the page that have the devices of one category dosen't have the style of the site

Comment: Can you show us all the content of `categories.blade.php` ?

Comment: @bayan how you are linking your styles into your app.?

Comment: i think its frequent problem with styles in laravel blade. just search about it! there's lot of pages about this problem.

Comment: @Amin idid't finde could you help me!

Comment: move your style files to public directory and:[do this!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214499/laravel-5-not-finding-css-files)

Comment: u have links for device.blade.php in master.blade.php?

Comment: Thank you too much @Amin

Answer (score 0):

move ur stylesto public folder into any subfolder..here i'm using devices as sub-folder and devices.css is my file..
place link like this in ur master blade.with ur folder and file names

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::to('/')}}/devices/devices.css">
```