# Invalid request (unexpected eof)- laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cmd

Hi I'm trying to load in app.css with the following laravel code. The parsley file is in the public folder of the application and when i render the page i get an error message - invalid request(unexpected eof).

Comment: past your example code with error if you want help

Comment: Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
[Thu Oct 12 15:37:41 2017] 127.0.0.1:65092 [200]: /css/app.css
[Thu Oct 12 15:37:42 2017] 127.0.0.1:65093 [200]: /js/app.js [Thu Oct 12 15:38:38 2017] 127.0.0.1:65112 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214499/laravel-5-not-finding-css-files see this

Comment: it's mistake with your braces.