# Laravel ajax response rendering html with include not working

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I created a clean external blade for rendering my result, but I will outputting a checkbox and checkbox needs the css and js. I'm trying to include it directly but no luck

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('materialize/css/materialize.min.css')}}">
<link href="{{asset('css/materializeicon.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

@if (!empty($permissions))
<div class="flex_3_container">
    @foreach ($permissions as $r)
        <div class="flex_3_item">test</div>
    @endforeach
</div>
@endif

//putting here doesn't work either
```

My controller

```
public function getExistingRolesPermission($id){
    $permissions = Permission::find($id);

    $returnHTML = view('renders.render')->with('permissions',$permissions)->render();
    return response()->json(array('output'=>'get_assigning', 'html'=>$returnHTML));

}
```

My response should have a background color of text what happen is just rendering a "test" word

```
if(data.output === 'get_assigning'){
    $('.display_section').html(data.html);

}
```

It only works if I put style directly

```
 .flex_3_containier
    display: flex
    flex-wrap: row wrap
    position: relative
    height: auto
    width: 300px

.flex_3_item
    display: inline-block
    margin: 4px
    //flex-grow: 1
    /* width: calc(100% * (1/4) - 10px - 1px) */
    flex: 0 1 calc(20% - 8px)
    background-color: blue
```

Comment: put all your css/js on the main page

Comment: try using the `public` folder instead of asset paths.

Comment: @admcfajn what do you mean? if i'm not mistaken asset paths are came from public files and on my network all paths are working well

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a look now that your question is revised.

Comment: It sounds like you have two problems: 1.) The css doesn't work, and 2.) you're not getting the expected error-response back from your api-call?

Comment: @admcfajn theres no any error, I doubt its on the initialization. But i don't know why it is not rendering the css and js when all my includes are ready?

Comment: @NaibSorion right then for the css and js not loading, you may want to put those files in a different folder or load them with a different syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214499/laravel-5-not-finding-css-files

Comment: Ok i just forgot to start run watch, my sass didn't compile its fine now lol